# Manually applying different colors in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, linegraph

`ggplot(data = s2[1:39,], aes(x=Month, y=Users, group=Year, col=Year)) + geom_line(size=1.3) + geom_point(size=4.5) + geom_point(size=4.0, color='#FFFFFF')  +  ggtitle("Seoul_year") +   scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)) + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)`

[image: ggplot result]

From the upper code I keep getting same blueish colors(per year) in plotting line graph in R.
However, I want to apply different color of lines in the graph.
Which code line should I fix?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
scale_color_gradient(low="red",high="black")
```

while red or black can be whatever, including HEX code.
It still means your Year variable is numeric though.

Comment: putting in "color=as.factor(Year)" was also the answer